# TH232 thermostat appears to reset every time I press any button

Tags: hvac, switch, thermostat, heating

I have my underfloor heating set on a program timer, but wanted to change this for the winter. However, any time I press ANY button, the screen lights up as it should, but then goes blank and resets, then back to the usual screen. I can make no manual changes, not even the time. There is power though as it is mains, not battery operated. Any advice please on how to fix? Or do I need a new one?

Comment: Since you didn't provide the manufacturer or  model number, there is little we can do. I would suggest reading the manual. If you don't have the manual, go to the manufacturer's website and try to locate it. How long has this problem existed? Has it always been this way or it is something new. If it is new, is there something that was recently changed that might have caused this problem?

Comment: Who makes this TH232 of yours?